# Java Double Round off to 2 decimal always

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I am trying to round off the double values to 2 decimal digits, however it's not working in all scenarios

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(round(25.0,2));  //25.0 - expected 25.00
    System.out.println(round(25.00d,2)); //25.0 - expected 25.00
    System.out.println(round(25,2));   //25.0 - expected 25.00
    System.out.println(round(25.666,2));  //25.67
}
```

In short, no matter whether decimal exists or not, always hold the values upto 2 decimal even if it needs to pad additional zeros.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may need to use decimal format instead of setScale.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two things that can be improved in your code.

First, casting double to BigDecimal in order to round it is very inefficient approach. You should use Math.round instead:

```
    double value = 1.125879D;
    double valueRounded = Math.round(value * 100D) / 100D;
```

Second, when you print or convert real number to string, you may consider using System.out.printf or String.format. In your case using format "%.2f" does the trick.

```
    System.out.printf("%.2f", valueRounded);
```

Comment: "First" part is necessary only if you need to get rounded value as double. Formatting with precision does proper rounding as well, so if the end goal of your program is to get string representation of the rounded value, all you need is `String.format` or `System.out.printf`.

Comment: That's not actually rounding like `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`, though. In fact, that's not rounding at all, just truncating.

Comment: @DavidConrad From my point of view both examples work according to RoundingMode.HALF_UP algorithm. Moreover, String.format is [declared to use this algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (search 'round half up algorithm' keyword there).

Comment: Good point. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5):

I use the format() function of String class. Much simpler code. The 2 in "%.2f" indicates the number of digits after the decimal point you want to display. The f in "%.2f" indicates that you are printing a floating point number. Here is the documentation on formatting a string (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

```
double number = 12.34567;
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", number));
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat two = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); //Make new decimal format

    System.out.println(two.format(25.0)); 

    System.out.println(two.format(25.00d));

    System.out.println(two.format(25));

    System.out.println(two.format(25.666));

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are converting `BigDecimal` back to `double` which essentially trim the trailing zeros.

You can return either `BigDecimal` or `BigDecimal.toPlainString()`.

```
public static String round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.toPlainString();
}
```